# Make sbt publish use proguard instead of package

Tags: scala, sbt, proguard

Using the plugin sbt-proguard, how do I make `sbt publish` depend on it and use its output jar rather than using the regular "package" and its output? Out-of-the-box if you type "publish" in the sbt shell then proguard is not invoked.

(Note: sbt-proguard is different from xsbt-proguard-plugin)